# Spring Vault Integration - read secrets from multiple paths

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-vault, vault

Is it possible to read secrets stored under multiple paths/contexts in Vault from Spring Boot application?

I assume, profiles should be used, but not sure and still didn't manage to configure profiles.

Approle authentication is used to connect Vault from Spring Boot application.

Spring Boot application configuration (`bootstrap.yaml`):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: poc-name

  cloud:
    vault:
      host: {vault-host}
      port: {vault-port}
      scheme: http

      authentication: approle
      app-role:
        role-id: {role-id}
        secret-id: {secret-id}

      kv:
        enabled: true
        application-name: poc-name
        default-context: test-secrets-1
        backend: secrets-backend
```

For example, if there is following structure:

```
secrets-backend
  - test-secrets-1
    - key1: value1
    - key2: value2
  - test-secrets-2
    - key3: value3
    - key4: value4
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes we can make use of multiple secrets, if they are under one secret engine.
We can provide multiple secrets in the `kv.application-name` attribute.

Here is the sample for the same:

```
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled: true
spring.cloud.vault.kv.backend: my-secret-engine
spring.cloud.vault.kv.application-name: secret1,secret2
spring.config.import: vault://my-secret-engine/secret1,vault://my-secret-engine/secret2
```